Get a list of Vimeo Video URL base on appx uploading time with Python and Vimeo API
as per title, I have very basic knowledge in Python, and I tried to learn how to use Vimeo API with it.
Can someone let me know if this is possible, and the part of the documentation that I can look for those information and function to be use? ( I think I should check the vimeo api documentation? but I spend hrs and still can't find it)
Or if it is not too much to ask, can someone provide the script so I can study accordingly?

Hi I did not understand your question... can you be more descriptive? are you trying to get your video urls or all video urls?

@charan vendra, I mean video urls on vimeo, yes likely 100, but I only need couple of them which are near to the time I request.

Yes, it is possible to retrieve a list of Vimeo video URLs based on approximate upload time using Python and the Vimeo API. You can start by looking at this solution which provides a Python script as a starting point.
Additionally, you should check the official Vimeo API documentation, specifically the section on making API requests, which might have more detailed examples and explanations.
Remember to install any necessary libraries such as requests if you haven’t already, and ensure you have the proper authentication set up to make requests to the Vimeo API.
